# "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor" file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, tensorflow

Hello I'm trying to run ios example project of tensorflow.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples

I could successfully download and open the XCode project.
But when I run, compiler error occurred at `#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"`.

Environment:

- XCode: 8.3.2
- OS: MacOS X Sierra

Comment: Did you `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/download_dependencies.sh` at the root of the repository?

Comment: Yes, and I did it again but the result was same.